# Monitor and log COM calls between two exe's

Tags: com

I have two applications, A.exe and B.exe.
B.exe implements various COM interfaces and is used by A.exe.

Can I somehow see and log all the calls which are made from A.exe to B.exe?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Have you seen this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505196/spying-on-com-objects/1507812#1507812 ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a look at ComTrace.

Comment: I recommend this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067784/is-there-a-way-to-watch-all-com-activity-on-a-computer